Trouble Understanding the hardware filters used by my EEG amplifier
First of all, let me introduce myself: I am a clinical neurologist and in the last few weeks I am delving into EEG quantitative analysis. I deeply apologize for posting in an engineering community without the necessary knowledge, but after much research I have thought that someone here might help me.
Basically, I use a Cadwell Arc Apollo EEG device. I know from the producer that the LF filter can be set as low as 0.16 Hz and the HF as high as 100 at 256 Hz sampling rate.
When I record an EEG I see the toggled filters on the screen (in my case: LF 0.5 Hz, HF 70 Hz, Notch ON) and my signal is clearly readable, as expected, both live and when I open the EEG for clinical review. However, when I exctract the edf and I analyse it on MATLAB I see that the EEG is unreadable prior to hard digital filtering (A/C noise is massive as it would be without notch). The spectrum is inconsistent with a 0.5-70 bandpass too, as, for example, the 100 Hz A/C harmonic is strongly seen. This makes me think that the filter that I see displayed during recording are pre-processing filters applied after the storage of the actual signal, at least in part. This makes sense in a Digital architecture.
My question is: How can I get to know the hardware filters that my system is applying to the signal, i.e. the physical HF and LF filters which impact the recorded signal, prior to successive digital filtering? I know from many sources that, given the flexibility of digital systems, the allowed bandpass prior to digital filtering is wide (e.g. 0.1 - 100 Hz), or even wider for other applications. Do you know if maybe some fixed physical filter settings are used? Does anyone of you have experience with similar EEG devices? Is there maybe some other issue that I might be overlooking?

Welcome! Your 100 Hz could come though several means into your system, although the source is the grid. Can you provide a block diagram or even better a schematic, along with what you have hooked up to it? If you float everything, battery powered, battery scope with no mains connections and what not, is it still present?

Sorry, but I do not understand the question. I deeply apologize, as, being a medical doctor, I have basically no knowledge. What diagram are you referring to? I do not know the architecture of my EEG device, only thing I know is that if I take the raw edf from my machine it is clearly less filtered than how it appears on the clinical reading program, so I think that the displayed filters are digital ones and I basically do not know what kind of physical filter was applied to the signal during the recording.

If it's a commercial EEG, someone should have solved this for you, but how have you connected what to it? How do you get the data off it?

I take the edf directly from the EEG program on the recording machine. That is, amplifier records the data which are processed on a computer where I can read and report the exams. Here I can look at the filtering options as described above. If from here I want to extract the edf file to examine on a third party program on my PC, I am allowed to do. When I do, the edf contains frequencies which would not be there if the actual filter applied during the recording were the ones displayed on the PC conncected to the EEG recorder. So, I don't know what physical HF and LF, aside of digital ones.

You probably need to talk to the EEG device vendor and ask them for transfer functions or FIR or IIR coefficients of their filters. Presumably someone paid good money for the thing, they should hopefully be coaxed into helping a customer...


How can I get to know the hardware filters that my system is applying to the signal, i.e. the physical HF and LF filters which impact the recorded signal, prior to successive digital filtering?

You can use a function generator to "sweep" the system. That is, a function generator is set to generate a sine wave and repeatedly sweep the frequency from some lower frequency (say 0.1Hz) to an upper frequency (say 200Hz).
The function generator output has to be scaled down using a resistor network, and that can then be fed into the EEG amplifier inputs.
Since you will know exactly what sine frequency and amplitude on the input was - from generator settings and resistor divider ratio - you can then derive the transfer function (e.g. a Bode plot) of the entire chain from voltage input to recorded digital file.
Typically the sweep repeats and the sweep mode is known, e.g. linear frequency sweep when \$\frac{df}{dt} = {\rm const}\$, or logarithmic sweep when \$d{\log f}{dt} = {\rm const}\$. That will make it easy to plot the amplitude vs frequency from the recorded signal - as well as phase.

Thank you for the advice, I will try and do something like this in case I am not able to gather the information form direct sources.
